# insert tags at the beginning and end of the line that contains the keyword

Tags: sed, awk

If anyone knows how this can be easily done, please tell me.I have out like this:

```
mac: 24:A4:3C:74:C0:49 name : SomeSome1 lastip : 192.168.1.178 txpower : 56 quality : 97 capacity : 95
mac: DC:9F:DB:62:10:BF name : SomeSome2 lastip : 192.168.1.58 txpower : 56 quality : 97 capacity : 11
mac: DC:9F:DB:3E:25:D8 name : SomeSome3 lastip : 192.168.1.48 txpower : 56 quality : 74 capacity : 10
mac: DC:9F:DB:3E:25:D8 name : SomeSome3 lastip : 192.168.1.48 txpower : 56 quality : 74 capacity : 8
```

Each line that contains the value **capacity** <= 10 I need to insert the side tags

I need like this:

```
mac: 24:A4:3C:74:C0:49 name : SomeSome1 lastip : 192.168.1.178 txpower : 56 quality : 97 capacity : 95
mac: DC:9F:DB:62:10:BF name : SomeSome2 lastip : 192.168.1.58 txpower : 56 quality : 97 capacity : 11
<div style=' width: 50%; background-color: red; color: white'>mac: DC:9F:DB:3E:25:D8 name : SomeSome3 lastip : 192.168.1.48 txpower : 56 quality : 74 capacity : 10</div>
<div style=' width: 50%; background-color: red; color: white'>mac: DC:9F:DB:3E:25:D8 name : SomeSome3 lastip : 192.168.1.48 txpower : 56 quality : 74 capacity : 8</div>
```

The system on which I plan to run:

```
BusyBox v1.11.2 (2012-10-12 17:12:28 EEST) multi-call binary
```

If anyone knows how this can be easily done, please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Busybox handy to test it but you can try something like:

```
awk '$NF<=10{print "<div style='"'"' width: 50%; background-color: red; color: white'"'"'>"$0"</div>";next}1' file
```

**Output:**

```
$ awk '$NF<=10{print "<div style='"'"' width: 50%; background-color: red; color: white'"'"'>"$0"</div>";next}1' file
mac: 24:A4:3C:74:C0:49 name : SomeSome1 lastip : 192.168.1.178 txpower : 56 quality : 97 capacity : 95
mac: DC:9F:DB:62:10:BF name : SomeSome2 lastip : 192.168.1.58 txpower : 56 quality : 97 capacity : 11
<div style=' width: 50%; background-color: red; color: white'>mac: DC:9F:DB:3E:25:D8 name : SomeSome3 lastip : 192.168.1.48 txpower : 56 quality : 74 capacity : 10</div>
<div style=' width: 50%; background-color: red; color: white'>mac: DC:9F:DB:3E:25:D8 name : SomeSome3 lastip : 192.168.1.48 txpower : 56 quality : 74 capacity : 8</div>
```

Comment: If the value of capacity is `<=` 10, tags should be added.

Comment: @axiom Sorry, I am not able to follow. Isn't the value of capacity the last field, so `$NF` usage seems to be correct? I just didnt follow how OP got an extra line for capacity of 8 which was not in his sample input.

Comment: Sorry I missed the fact that OP has missed a line in the input. I was addressing `not sure how did you get the last line in your sample output` part of your answer.

Comment: @axiom Oh ok, the answer I posted would work if there exist a capacity of `<=10`. It just wont create one that doesn't exist. `;)`.

Comment: I'm going to use this code in php, I do not understand what special characters still need to hide:                                                 awk '$NF<=10{print \"<div style='\"'\"' width: 50%; background-color: red; color: white'\"'\"'>\"$0\"</div>\";next}1' file

Answer (score 1):

As horrible as it looks, the following will work :

```
sed "s/\(^.*capacity : 10\)/<div style=' width: 50%; background-color: red; color: white'>\1<\/div>/g;s/\(^.*capacity : [0-9]$\)/<div style=' width: 50%; background-color: red; color: white'>\1<\/div>/g" t
```

Where `t` is the input file.

I first make the substitution for `10`, and then add tags where value is `< 10`.